# TDE Scalar Type for Array

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm trying to retrun a JSON Array object as a column in TDE. What should be the scalar type?

I'm using MarkLogic 10.0-1. My JSON document is in nested structure and I want to expose row view using TDE with fields containing an array object. I tried using scalarType as string but tde.nodeDataExtract errors out. Is there a way to overcome this?

Given below contains sample document and template

```
    var doc1 = xdmp.toJSON(
      {
        "customer":{
          "Name": "afgasdfasfasffasf", 
          "Addr": [
            {
              "AddrTypeCd": "MailingAddress", 
              "Addr1": "911 FORBES AVE", 
              "Addr2": "SUITE XXX", 
              "CityName": "asdfasfd", 
              "StateProvCd": "PA", 
              "PostalCode": "15219"
            }, 
            {
              "AddrTypeCd": "OfficeAddress", 
              "Addr1": "911 Watson AVE", 
              "Addr2": "SUITE XXX", 
              "CityName": "asdfasfd", 
              "StateProvCd": "CT", 
              "PostalCode": "15119"
            }
          ]
        }
      });

    var rowtde1 = xdmp.toJSON(
    {
      "template":{
        "context":"/customer",
        "rows":[
          {
            "schemaName":"Schemas",
            "viewName":"SampleCustomer",
            "columns":[
              {
                "name":"CustomerName",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"Name"
              },
              {
                "name":"Addr",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"Addr"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    );



tde.nodeDataExtract([doc1],[rowtde1]);
```

Execution Error:

```
[javascript] TDE-EVALFAILED: 
tde.nodeDataExtract([Document({"customer":{"Name":"afgasdfasfasffasf", 
"Addr":[{"AddrTypeCd":"MailingAddress", ...}, ...]}})], 
[Document({"template":{"context":"/customer", "rows": 
[{"schemaName":"Schemas", ...}]}})]) -- Eval for Column Addr='Addr' 
returns multiple values (only one is expected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a slightly different approach will get you where you want to go. Let's change the context from `/customer` to `/customer/Addr`. Now TDE can work to extract one row for each item in the array. (If you had a bunch of data you wanted to extract that isn't in the array, you'd use more than one template to populate the index.

```
 var doc1 = xdmp.toJSON(
      {
        "customer":{
          "Name": "afgasdfasfasffasf", 
          "Addr": [
            {
              "AddrTypeCd": "MailingAddress", 
              "Addr1": "911 FORBES AVE", 
              "Addr2": "SUITE XXX", 
              "CityName": "asdfasfd", 
              "StateProvCd": "PA", 
              "PostalCode": "15219"
            }, 
            {
              "AddrTypeCd": "OfficeAddress", 
              "Addr1": "911 Watson AVE", 
              "Addr2": "SUITE XXX", 
              "CityName": "asdfasfd", 
              "StateProvCd": "CT", 
              "PostalCode": "15119"
            }
          ]
        }
      });

    var rowtde1 = xdmp.toJSON(
    {
      "template":{
        "context":"/customer/Addr",
        "rows":[
          {
            "schemaName":"Schemas",
            "viewName":"CustomerAddress",
            "columns":[
              {
                "name":"CustomerName",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"../../Name"
              },
              {
                "name":"AddrTypeCd",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"AddrTypeCd"
              },
              {
                "name":"Addr1",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"Addr1"
              },
              {
                "name":"Addr2",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"Addr2"
              },
              {
                "name":"CityName",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"CityName"
              },
              {
                "name":"StateProvCd",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"StateProvCd"
              },
              {
                "name":"PostalCode",
                "scalarType":"string",
                "val":"PostalCode"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    );



tde.nodeDataExtract([doc1],[rowtde1]);
```

This gets you one row for each address added to the Schemas.CustomerAddress view.

---

Adding info based on this comment: "I'm trying to avoid Joins as well as multiple views to build and maintain. Every new template, has a cost on the server due to indexing."

It's worth remembering that MarkLogic views are implemented differently from views in a relational database. Under the hood, MarkLogic's views are implemented using the triple index, so there will be joins regardless. The approach I laid out above is the commonly used way to handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm trying to avoid Joins as well as multiple views to build and maintain. Every new template, has a cost on the server due to indexing. Is there a way to bring a specific portion of JSON (ie., Addr array in my example) as a column in TDE? I've app developers and testers that are proficient with SQL and JSON and I'm trying to provide them TDE views to quickly query their data and at the same time put very less stress on the cluster that is critical from performance standpoint for applications.